# How to get account and contact of a particular case using soql query in salesforce?

Tags: apex, soql

I want to show accounts and contacts data of a particular case in a form. how can i query the same using soql query in salesforce. 
I have a custom object named Work_Order__c which is having a master-detail relationship with CASE object.
I am trying to write a below mentioned query, but the inner query is giving error.

```
select Id,Case__r.CaseNumber,Case__r.Description,Name,
Status__c,Priority__c,Description__c,City__c,Street__c,Zip__c,
(select Case__r.Account.Name, Case__r.Contact.Name from Work_Orders__r)
from Work_Order__c where Id = 'a024B0000025L6G'
```

Comment: Why are you using this inner query? If you replace inner query`(select Case__r.Account.Name, Case__r.Contact.Name from Work_Orders__r)` with `Case__r.Account.Name, Case__r.Contact.Name` it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for inner query here. Because the Account and Contact details are present in Case object which is master of Work Order object.

So

```
Select Id,Case__r.CaseNumber,Case__r.Description,Name,
Status__c,Priority__c,Description__c,City__c,Street__c,Zip__c,
Case__r.Account.Name, Case__r.Contact.Name 
from Work_Order__c where Id = 'a024B0000025L6G'
```

will give you the Account and Contact details of Case to which your current Work Order is related to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works but Case__r.Account.Name, Case__r.Contact.Name value is  [object Object] how can i get single record for the same.

Comment: If you query in developer console and double click it, it will show object object only. But if you use it in apex you will get the values.

Comment: Before double click also the value is [object Object].

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different angle. I recently learned about making custom object classes.
Some of the details may be wrong because I don't know how all of your objects are set up, but hopefully this will be useful to you.

```
//declare your new class
public class WorkOrderCaseThing{
    public Work_Order__c theWorkOrder{get;set;}
    public list(Case) theCases{get;set;}
}

//create method which returns a list of objects of your new class
public List(WorkOrderCaseThing) getWorkOrderCaseThings{
    //the returning list
    public list(WorkOrderCaseThing) wOCTList = new list(WorkOrderCaseThing);

    //list of work orders you wish to display
    public list(Work_Order__c) workOrderList = new list(Work_Order__c);
    workOrderList = [SELECT Name, Case__c FROM Work_Order__c];

    //list of all cases
    list(Case__c) caseList = new List(Case);
    caseList = [SELECT Name, Work_Order__c FROM Case]

    //list of cases you will return
    list(Case__c) newCaseList = new List(Case);

    //now it's time to make some objects
    // for each work order in your list
    for (Work_Order__c workOrder : workOrderList){

        //make a new thing
        WorkOrderCaseThing thing = new WorkOrderCaseThing();

        //make current work order your new thing's theWorkOrder
        thing.theWorkOrder = workOrder;

        //create the list of cases related to your work order
        for (Case case : caseList){
            if (case.Work_Order__c == workOrder){
            newCaseList.add(case);
            }
        }

        //make that list the thing's theCases
        thing.theCases = newCaseList;

        //add your thing to your list of objects
        wOCTList.add(thing);
    }
    //return your object list
    return wOCTList;
}
```

Be sure to use lists or sets to avoid using soql queries inside of for loops.